# HTML tabe draw a line between 2 tds

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a requirement with basic HTML and css. I want to create a table row and td's dynamically and i want to draw a line between td's like below.
in the sample pic, there are 4 td's and connected with a line.

kindly can anyone help me how to achive this

[image]

Comment: Assign background images to the `<tr>` and the `<td>`s.

Comment: Hi Chris.. Thanks for your prompt reply. i will use background images for tds. then i can set hexagon image. but here problem is how to draw horizontal line between tds

Comment: Here's a starting point, I had to assign the background image to the table itself though: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/penho2u0/

Comment: Chris.. excellent. but that line should starts from middle of the first td and ends in middle of the last td. It should not exceeds :(

Comment: Please post your "*[mcve]*" code, explain the problems you've had with your own attempted solutions. You may want to read the guidance about "*[ask]*."

Comment: the below one is closest to my code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  table {
  border-spacing: 3em 0;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 48%, #000, #ffffff 52%);
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. Edit your question and format it properly there.

Answer (score 0):

Use div's and css for arange content like this:

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 45px;
  background: black;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.hexagon:before {
  top: 4px;  /* border width */
  left: 4px;  /* border width */
  height: calc(100% - 8px);  /* 100% - (2 * border width) */
  width: calc(100% - 8px);  /* 100% - (2 * border width) */
  background: white;
}
.hexagon, .hexagon:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
.hexagon div{
  font-weight:bold;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
.interval{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width:30px;
  height:4px;
  top:8px;
  background-color:black;
  margin:-4px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="hexagon"><div>1</div></div>
   <div class="interval"></div>
   <div class="hexagon"><div>2</div></div>
   <div class="interval"></div>
   <div class="hexagon"><div>3</div></div>
   <div class="interval"></div>
   <div class="hexagon"><div>4</div></div>
```

Comment: hi all. thanks for your unconditional support. i have finally achieved. now it is working